# Creating multiple ggplot2 boxplots via looping around mulltiple y axis observations

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a `df` with as 700 x 500

```
  Time   Cell1 Cell2 Cell3  Cell4   Cell5   PID   Panels   
  T1    51.7  37.7  11.80  1.89    7.28     111   p1
  T2    49.8  34.8  10.40  1.29    6.01     111   p1
  T3    55.1  34.0  7.61   2.78    6.99     111   p1
  T1    44.1  55.4  29.90  5.26    6.91     112   p2
  T2    58.4  32.6  22.40  7.89    4.28     112   p2
  T3    46.7  49.9  25.20  7.89    4.70     112   p2
```

Now I want to make `boxplots` of the distribution of each `Cell1, Cell2 ...` (y-axis) over `Time`( here 3-time points)

I need to write the `ggplot2()` function in a way that it can cycle through my column names of the `Cell` and make separate `boxplots`, the `fill`, and the color need to be by `Panels` and I also need my `y-axis` to be `log scale`. The current `df` is not `log-scaled`(I can take care of that if it's of a hassle of an argument pass)

my `snippet` fails.

I am not able to figure out how to make the code cycle through the df columns headers. Trying to figure out how to pass the `y-axis` string argument get them mapped to `aes` of `ggplot()` for their values in `df`. Here I understand that the strings are being passed as an argument but not being recognized as a column in the `df` (please correct me if I am wrong).

Any suggestions/workaround will be appreciated. I just do not want to write the `ggplot()` function so many times. Can't figure out how to make the loop here or make a function around the plot.

```
Cell_list=colnames(df[6:10])

# create for loop to produce ggplot2 graphs 
for (i in seq_along(Cell_list)) { 

    plot <- 
        ggplot (df, aes(x=df$Time,y=Cell_list[i], col=df$Panels,.desc=TRUE))+ 
        geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0 ) + 
        geom_point(aes(fill=df$Panels, col=NULL),shape=21, alpha=0.5, size=2, 
                   position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.2))+
        theme_bw() + xlab("")
    # print plots to screen
    print(plot)
}
```

Comment: You should *never* use `data$column` inside `aes()`, it will mess things up. `aes()` expects unquoted column names. When you need to loop over columns, there are a few options described at the linked FAQ. An old, but easy, way would be to use `aes_string()` instead of aes(), which expects string (quoted) column names: `ggplot(df, aes_string(x = "Time", y = Cell_list[i], color = "Panels")) + ...`. You can log the y axis with `+scale_y_continuous, trans = "log")`

Comment: This is amazing, thanks for this solution. I should have searched well. Many thanks for also pointing to the FAQ.